# proper ideals of $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

$\oplus_{i\in I}A_i$ denotes the $c_0$ direct sum of $C^*$ algebras $A_i$, $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ is the $l^\infty$ direct sum of $A_i$.We know that $\oplus_{i\in I}A_i$ is the essential ideal of $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$.

Do there exist other proper ideals of $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ which contain $\oplus_{i\in I}A_i$? If there exist,how to construct these ideals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For any non-principal [ultrafilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter) $U$ on $I$, you can consider the ideal of elements of $\prod A_i$ which are equal to zero $U$-almost everywhere. The quotient of $\prod A_i$ by this ideal is the corresponding [ultraproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraproduct).

Comment: @mathrookie: I mean the subset of $I$ on which some element $\prod a_i \in \prod A_i$ is equal to zero lies in $U$.